# Memory usage with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor in Python3

Tags: python, json, concurrency, malloc, urllib

I am building a script to download and parse benefits information for health insurance plans on Obamacare exchanges. Part of this requires downloading and parsing the plan benefit JSON files from each individual insurance company. In order to do this, I am using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` with 6 workers to download each file (with urllib), parse and loop thru the JSON and extract the relevant info (which is stored in nested dictionary within the script).

(running Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32)

The problem is that when I do this concurrently, the script does not seem to release the memory after it has downloaded\parsed\looped thru a JSON file, and after a while, it crashes, with `malloc` raising a memory error.

When I do it serially--with a simple `for in` loop-- however,the program does not crash nor does it take an extreme amount of memory.

```
def load_json_url(url, timeout):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' })
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
    return json.loads(resp) 



 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_json_url, url, 60): url for url in formulary_urls}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                # The below timeout isn't raising the TimeoutError.
                data = future.result(timeout=0.01)
                for item in data:
                        if item['rxnorm_id']==drugid: 
                            for row in item['plans']:
                                print (row['drug_tier'])
                                (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['drug_tier']=row['drug_tier']
                                (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['prior_authorization']=row['prior_authorization']
                                (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['step_therapy']=row['step_therapy']
                                (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['quantity_limit']=row['quantity_limit']

            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))


            else:
                downloaded_plans=downloaded_plans+1
```

Answer (score 13):

It's not your fault. `as_complete()` doesn't release its futures until it completes. There's an issue logged already: https://bugs.python.org/issue27144

For now, I think the majority approach is to wrap as_complete() inside another loop that chunkify to a sane number of futures, depending on how much RAM you want to spend and how big your result will be. It'll block on each chunk until all job is gone before going to next chunk so be slower or potentially stuck in the middle for a long time, but I see no other way for now, though will keep this answer posted when there's a smarter way.

Comment: A related issue is [#34168](https://bugs.python.org/issue34168).

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative solution, you can call `add_done_callback` on your futures and not use `as_completed` at all. The key is NOT keeping references to futures. So `future_to_url` list in original question is a bad idea.

What I've done is basically:

```
def do_stuff(future):
    res = future.result()  # handle exceptions here if you need to

f = executor.submit(...)
f.add_done_callback(do_stuff)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use the standard module “concurrent.futures” and want to simultaneously process several million data, then a queue of workers will take up all the free memory.

You can use **bounded-pool-executor**.
https://github.com/mowshon/bounded_pool_executor

```
pip install bounded-pool-executor
```

example:

```
from bounded_pool_executor import BoundedProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def do_job(num):
    sleep_sec = randint(1, 10)
    print('value: %d, sleep: %d sec.' % (num, sleep_sec))
    sleep(sleep_sec)

with BoundedProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as worker:
    for num in range(10000):
        print('#%d Worker initialization' % num)
        worker.submit(do_job, num)
```

Comment: is there a way to get the number of free workers from ThreadPoolExecutor?

Answer (score 2):

dodysw has correctly pointed out that the common solution is to chunkify the inputs and submit chunks of tasks to the executor. He has also correctly pointed out that you lose some performance by waiting for each chunk to be processed completely before starting to process the next chunk.

I suggest a better solution that will feed a **continuous stream of tasks** to the executor while enforcing an upper bound on the maximum number of parallel tasks in order to keep the memory footprint low.

The trick is to use `concurrent.futures.wait` to keep track of the futures that have been completed and those that are still pending completion:

```
def load_json_url(url):
    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
        return json.loads(resp), None
    except Exception as e:
        return url, e

MAX_WORKERS = 6
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
    futures_done = set()
    futures_notdone = set()
    for url in formulary_urls:
        futures_notdone.add(executor.submit(load_json_url, url))

        if len(futures_notdone) >= MAX_WORKERS:
            done, futures_notdone = concurrent.futures.wait(futures_notdone, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            futures_done.update(done)

# Process results.
downloaded_plans = 0
for future in futures_done:
    json, exc = future.result()
    if exc:
        print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (json, exc))
    else:
        downloaded_plans += 1
        for item in data:
            if item['rxnorm_id'] == drugid:
                for row in item['plans']:
                    print(row['drug_tier'])
                    (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['drug_tier'] = row['drug_tier']
                    (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['prior_authorization'] = row['prior_authorization']
                    (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['step_therapy'] = row['step_therapy']
                    (plansid_dict[row['plan_id']])['quantity_limit'] = row['quantity_limit']
```

Of course, you could also process the results inside the loop regularly in order to empty the `futures_done` from time to time. For example, you could do that each time the number of items in `futures_done` exceeds 1000 (or any other amount that fits your needs). This might come in handy if your dataset is very large and the results alone would result in a lot of memory usage.

Comment: I tried this one, its working for a small amount of datas, but when it's about millions, the program is getting slower and slower with time